# Single line 'var' declarations, or one per line?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm looking at Douglas Crockford's [Code Conventions for JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) document, and he's saying that `var`s should be alphabetical, and one per line.

```
var a;                  // array of class names
var c = node.className; // the node's classname
var i;                  // loop counter
```

However, the [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) (and jsHint) standard is to declare them on a single line, and it throws this error if done Crockford's way

> too many var statements

Therefore, jsLint wants it done like this.

```
var a, c = node.className, i;
```

This seems quite contradictory to me, and though probably quite minute in the overall scope of programming, I'm hoping to get this right before I get it wrong.

What is the generally accepted practice when declaring JavaScript vars?

Comment: I'm voting one per line.

Comment: Another one-per-line advocate; much easier to read, IMO.

Comment: If you need to arrange them alphabetically, I'd argue that the function's got too big...

Comment: I tend to do one per line, but only one `var` statement (indent the following identifiers to the same place as the first one). But it's just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Wow, controversial question. Many great answers and yet many close votes as well.

Comment: I've used single var, multiple lines (break after comma) so far. But I realised it causes issues when debugging (it's a complex browserify client/server project). So I'm thinking of switching to multiple var for the require blocks to get cleaner stack traces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LINT wants a single `var` declaration statement, but it can be spread over multiple lines.

```
var a, b, c;
```

or

```
var a,
    b,
    c;
```

The reason it wants a single statement is to avoid any confusion about which variables belong to the local scope. With a single var statement, all locally scoped variables are contained to a single location within the scope and anyone can read the code quickly to see what they are.

It is further recommended that this declaration statement be at the top of the scope, since the JavaScript hoisting mechanism moves them there before execution anyway. By writing your code to expect that statement at the top of the scope, the hoisting mechanism can't cause any unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Neither way is wrong, but I generally prefer to use single line style declarations at the beginning of a code block. The most important thing is to keep it consistent. Example:

```
function() {
  var foo = "bar",
      number = 123,
      etc = "...";

  // stuff..
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jdc0589 this is helpful. I guess I shouldn't have said "get it wrong" as I know both ways work. I'm more shooting for the generally accepted method, which by the evidence in the answers, points to this approach for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Even a combination is fine. This is all about preference. If you are working with a team, then ask about the preference and keep it consistent.

```
var a, 
    c = node.className, 
    i;
```

Comment: ah yes, this is very good. Fits both directions. Doesn't violate jsLint, and still adheres to Crockford's standard.

Answer (score 2):

The argument is mostly a style discussion, however, it is far more important to **agree on a standard** and **have your team use it consistently**.

Answer (score 2):

Another option (it's the one I use) is:

```
 var a = ...,
     b = ...,
     c, d;
```

This makes it clear how many variables I'm declaring and that they're all related in some way (since I'm declaring them in the same space, they basically always are). It also helps differentiate between variables that already have values and ones that don't. That said, I only declare variables without assigning very rarely.

Unless I'm working with code that follows a different standard, this is what I do. And that's the most important thing: follow the style of your project. Otherwise, go by your preference. If you really don't care, use my style ;)

Comment: "makes it clear"? I don't follow. A quick glance shows you're declaring three variables , since there are three lines. However, a closer inspection shows you're actually declaring four. Do you really think using three lines to declare four variables is clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare multiple variables and assign them in the same line. It is a matter of personal preference.